# Can't Draw to Gtk.GlArea With OpenGL

Tags: go, opengl, gtk

I am trying to draw to gtk.GlArea with opengl. But its not showing. Probably I am doing something very stupid but I couldn't figure out what I am doing wrong. At first I am tried to draw an image but then I realized that I can't draw anything.
I am currently using go 1.20. I executed an example with python and it works so there is no problem with hardware or drivers.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/diamondburned/gotk4/pkg/gdk/v4"
    "github.com/diamondburned/gotk4/pkg/gio/v2"
    "github.com/diamondburned/gotk4/pkg/gtk/v4"
    "github.com/go-gl/gl/v4.1-core/gl"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

const appID = "com.github.diamondburned.gotk4-examples.gtk4.drawingarea"

var program uint32

var (
    square = []float32{
        -0.5, 0.5, 0,
        -0.5, -0.5, 0,
        0.5, 0.5, 0,
        0.5, -0.5, 0,
    }
)

var vao uint32

const vertexShaderSource = `
    #version 410
    in vec3 vp;
    void main() {
        gl_Position = vec4(vp, 1.0);
    }
` + "\x00"

const fragmentShaderSource = `
    #version 410
    out vec4 frag_colour;
    void main() {
        frag_colour = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
    }
` + "\x00"

func main() {
    app := gtk.NewApplication(appID, gio.ApplicationFlagsNone)
    app.ConnectActivate(func() { activate(app) })

    if code := app.Run(os.Args); code > 0 {
        os.Exit(code)
    }
}

func render(area *gtk.GLArea, context *gdk.GLContext) bool {
    context.MakeCurrent()
    gl.ClearColor(0.5, 0, 0, 0)
    gl.Clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    gl.UseProgram(program)
    //gl.Enable(gl.TEXTURE_2D)
    //gl.BindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture.ID)
    gl.BindVertexArray(vao)
    //gl.ActiveTexture(texture.ID)
    gl.DrawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 1)
    //gl.Disable(gl.TEXTURE_2D)
    //gl.Flush()
    return true
}

func onRealize(area *gtk.GLArea) {
    area.MakeCurrent()
    program = initOpenGL()
    gl.MatrixMode(gl.PROJECTION)
    gl.Ortho(0, 800, 480, 0, -1, 1)
    gl.LinkProgram(program)
    vao = makeVao(square)
}

func activate(app *gtk.Application) {
    window := gtk.NewApplicationWindow(app)
    err := gl.Init()
    if err != nil {
        println("error", err)
    }
    glArea := gtk.NewGLArea()
    glArea.Connect("render", render)
    glArea.Connect("realize", onRealize)
    window.SetTitle("drawingarea - gotk4 Example")
    window.SetChild(glArea)
    window.SetDefaultSize(800, 480)
    window.Show()
}

func compileShader(source string, shaderType uint32) (uint32, error) {
    shader := gl.CreateShader(shaderType)

    csources, free := gl.Strs(source)
    gl.ShaderSource(shader, 1, csources, nil)
    free()
    gl.CompileShader(shader)

    var status int32
    gl.GetShaderiv(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS, &status)
    if status == gl.FALSE {
        var logLength int32
        gl.GetShaderiv(shader, gl.INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength)

        log := strings.Repeat("\x00", int(logLength+1))
        gl.GetShaderInfoLog(shader, logLength, nil, gl.Str(log))

        return 0, fmt.Errorf("failed to compile %v: %v", source, log)
    }

    return shader, nil
}

func makeVao(points []float32) uint32 {
    var vbo uint32
    gl.GenBuffers(1, &vbo)
    gl.BindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
    gl.BufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 4*len(points), gl.Ptr(points), gl.STATIC_DRAW)

    gl.GenVertexArrays(1, &vao)
    gl.BindVertexArray(vao)
    gl.EnableVertexAttribArray(0)
    gl.BindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
    gl.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, nil)

    return vao
}

func initOpenGL() uint32 {
    vertexShader, err := compileShader(vertexShaderSource, gl.VERTEX_SHADER)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fragmentShader, err := compileShader(fragmentShaderSource, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    prog := gl.CreateProgram()
    gl.AttachShader(prog, vertexShader)
    gl.AttachShader(prog, fragmentShader)
    gl.LinkProgram(prog)
    return prog
}
```